JavaFX and TableView with split column get WidthProperty
I'm trying to retrieve the widthProperty of my parent column to assign it to my label but I can't.
Without Split Column is ok

And with Split column widthProperty not working

I manage to recover those of the others simple column. In this exemple I want to get Name column Parent widthProperty.
Main code
package test;
    
    import java.io.IOException;
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    import javafx.scene.Parent;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class Test extends Application {
        
        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("main.fxml"));                
            
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
            
            primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
        
    }

FXML Code
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    
    <?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
    
    <ScrollPane fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/22" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="test.MainController">
       <content>
          <VBox prefHeight="398.0" prefWidth="598.0">
             <children>
                <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                   <children>
                      <TextArea fx:id="lb_Paper" prefHeight="200.0" promptText="Paper" wrapText="true" />
                      <TextArea fx:id="lb_PC" prefHeight="200.0" promptText="PC" wrapText="true" />
                      <TextArea fx:id="lb_Name" prefHeight="200.0" promptText="Complete Name" wrapText="true" />
                      <TextArea fx:id="lb_Movies" prefHeight="200.0" promptText="Movies" wrapText="true" />
                   </children>
                </HBox>
                <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                   <children>
                      <TableView fx:id="tb_test" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                        <columns>
                          <TableColumn fx:id="column_Paper" prefWidth="75.0" text="Paper" />
                          <TableColumn fx:id="column_PC" prefWidth="75.0" text="PC" />
                            <TableColumn fx:id="column_Name" prefWidth="75.0" text="Name" />
                            <TableColumn fx:id="column_Movies" prefWidth="75.0" text="Movies" />
                        </columns>
                         <columnResizePolicy>
                            <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                         </columnResizePolicy>
                      </TableView>
                   </children>
                </HBox>
             </children>
          </VBox>
       </content>
    </ScrollPane>

FXMLController Code
package test;
    
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ResourceBundle;
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
    import javafx.scene.control.Label;
    import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
    import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
    import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
       
    public class MainController implements Initializable {
    
        @FXML
        private TextArea lb_Paper;
        @FXML
        private TextArea lb_PC;
        @FXML
        private TextArea lb_Name;
        @FXML
        private TextArea lb_Movies;
        @FXML
        private TableView<?> tb_test;
        @FXML
        private TableColumn<?, ?> column_Paper;
        @FXML
        private TableColumn<?, ?> column_PC;
        @FXML
        private TableColumn<?, ?> column_Name;
        @FXML
        private TableColumn<?, ?> column_Movies;
    
        @Override
        public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
            
                TableColumn firstactivitePedaCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
                TableColumn secondactivitePedaCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
                column_Name.getColumns().addAll(firstactivitePedaCol, secondactivitePedaCol);
                
                tb_test.setPlaceholder(new Label("Contexte"));
                
                lb_Paper.prefWidthProperty().bind(column_Paper.widthProperty());
                lb_Paper.minWidthProperty().bind(column_Paper.widthProperty());
                lb_Paper.maxWidthProperty().bind(column_Paper.widthProperty());
                
                lb_PC.prefWidthProperty().bind(column_PC.widthProperty());
                lb_PC.minWidthProperty().bind(column_PC.widthProperty());
                lb_PC.maxWidthProperty().bind(column_PC.widthProperty());
                
                lb_Name.prefWidthProperty().bind(column_Name.widthProperty());
                lb_Name.minWidthProperty().bind(column_Name.widthProperty());
                lb_Name.maxWidthProperty().bind(column_Name.widthProperty());
                
                lb_Movies.prefWidthProperty().bind(column_Movies.widthProperty());
                lb_Movies.minWidthProperty().bind(column_Movies.widthProperty());
                lb_Movies.maxWidthProperty().bind(column_Movies.widthProperty());
        }    
        
    }

Thx in advance for your reply

Apparently the parent column's width property is not synced with the sum of its visible children's widths. I suspect this could be considered a bug. But you can create a binding that is the sum of the child column's widths manually. For example:
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class Main extends Application {

  private TableColumn<Student, Integer> idCol;
  private TableColumn<Student, ?> nameCol;
  private TableColumn<Student, String> firstNameCol;
  private TableColumn<Student, String> lastNameCol;

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    var bottom = createTableView();
    var top = createTextAreas();

    var root = new VBox(top, bottom);
    VBox.setVgrow(bottom, Priority.ALWAYS);

    var scene = new Scene(root, 600.0, 500.0);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  private HBox createTextAreas() {
    var idArea = new TextArea();
    idArea.setPromptText("ID");
    idArea.setPrefRowCount(5);
    idArea.setMinSize(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE, Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
    idArea.setMaxSize(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE, Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
    idArea.prefWidthProperty().bind(idCol.widthProperty());

    var nameArea = new TextArea();
    nameArea.setPromptText("Full name");
    nameArea.setPrefRowCount(5);
    nameArea.setMinSize(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE, Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
    nameArea.setMaxSize(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE, Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
    nameArea
        .prefWidthProperty()
        .bind(firstNameCol.widthProperty().add(lastNameCol.widthProperty()));

    var box = new HBox(idArea, nameArea);
    HBox.setHgrow(idArea, Priority.NEVER);
    HBox.setHgrow(nameArea, Priority.NEVER);

    return box;
  }

  private TableView<Student> createTableView() {
    var table = new TableView<Student>();
    table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY_FLEX_LAST_COLUMN);
    table.getItems().addAll(new Student(0, "John", "Doe"), new Student(1, "Jane", "Doe"));

    idCol = new TableColumn<>("ID");
    setValueFactory(idCol, Student::id);
    table.getColumns().add(idCol);

    nameCol = new TableColumn<>("Name");
    table.getColumns().add(nameCol);

    firstNameCol = new TableColumn<>("First");
    setValueFactory(firstNameCol, Student::firstName);
    nameCol.getColumns().add(firstNameCol);

    lastNameCol = new TableColumn<>("Last");
    setValueFactory(lastNameCol, Student::lastName);
    nameCol.getColumns().add(lastNameCol);

    return table;
  }

  private <T> void setValueFactory(TableColumn<Student, T> column, Callback<Student, T> extractor) {
    column.setCellValueFactory(cdf -> {
      var value = extractor.call(cdf.getValue());
      return new SimpleObjectProperty<>(value);
    });
  }

  record Student(int id, String firstName, String lastName) {}
}

The part that creates the "sum binding" is here:
nameArea
    .prefWidthProperty()
    .bind(firstNameCol.widthProperty().add(lastNameCol.widthProperty()));

If you don't prefer the fluent API then you can use the Bindings class:
nameArea
    .prefWidthProperty()
    .bind(Bindings.add(firstNameCol.widthProperty(), lastNameCol.widthProperty()));

